# "Post installing" Ubuntu on a Hyper-V virtual computer

Tags: ubuntu, hyper-v

I am trying to use Ubuntu in parallel to Windows 10 just to be able to use some python libraries that are not available for Windows; creating a full-fledged Ubuntu partition is not an option.
I had already tried WSL but failed to get a GUI up and running.

Then I managed to install Ubuntu on Hyper-V, but because of the small initially allocated disk size it wa not possible to install anaconda.

So after some googling I found out that using a fixed size disk could solve the problem.

I have now a sufficiently large virtual generation 2 drive with 255GB but no operating system on it.
Icouldn't find any way to initiate installation of Ubuntu on the existing virtual drive.

[image]

So what I want to do is to install Ubuntu on the UbuntuVM virtual computer depicted above without creating a new virtual computer in Hyper-V.

As I am new to this topic simple connect the dots help would help me most

Comment: "So after some googling I found out that using a fixed size disk could solve the problem." that sounds like a bit of vague term. Don't think it is what you mean. You probably just want to increase the size of the virtual storage device, and then grow the partition containing your data on Ubuntu.

Comment: @MarcusMüller the default that Hyper-V did was to create a disk with fexible size, starting with 12GB up to 64GB and that made installation of anaconda fail because insufficient disk space; I therefore wanted to have a much higher initial size.
According to https://www.nakivo.com/blog/how-to-create-fixed-size-hard-disk-hyper-v-vm/ having a fixed size large enough has advantages; that convinced me to install a fixed size disk - now I have it but am stuck with installing an os on it.

Comment: yes, you can increase the size of these flexible size disks, I think. Not sure how, though. I might not be the optimal audience – you're asking about a Windows software problem there :)